# Why isnt my bubble sort method working?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I want to try to figure it out, I just kind of need to be pointed in the right direction. Please don't just write the solution, I would like to understand what I need to do to make it work.

```
    static void bubbleSort() {
        int [] a = {1,3,4,2,5};
        int [] b = new int[a.length];
        int j = 0;

        for(int c = 0;c <= a.length;c++){//this loop doesnt even do anything??? 
            for(int i = 0;i<a.length-j;i++){

                if(a[i]>a[i+1]){
                    b[i] = a[i+1];
                    b[i+1] = a[i];
                    j++;
                }
                else{
                    b[i] = a[i];
                    b[i+1] = a[i+1];
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i< b.length ; i++)
            System.out.println(b[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You should use the debugger to step through your program line-by-line, to discover where its behaviour diverges from what you hoped for.

Comment: Also, it helps if you tell us what exactly isn't working. What is the output? What do you expect the output to be? What did you try already that led to improvement? Where do you think the problem might be? Use the [edit] link to make further improvements. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hint: why are you trying to copy and sort at the same time?

Comment: what does System.out print? 1, 3, 2, 4, 5? you're saving ur result in a different array, you should save it in a instead of b, and use a temp variable to hold the value. and c doesnt do anything ^^ you dont use it in ur code. Your just running it from c to a.length

Comment: You basically just keep repeating the same stuff again and again.  Do away with `b` completely and sort only `a`.  (Find a word/diagram description of bubble sort on the web and follow it.)

Comment: hmm, just dont use b, if you swap a[i] and a[i+1], that should do the trick

Comment: Bubble sort can be done inplace easily, why are you using an extra array and increasing the overhead?

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code -

1) You don't need an extra array 'b', bubble sort can be done inplace.

2) Think the use of 'j', replace it with 'c' and check how this makes the difference in the looping.

3) Your new sorted array is coming up in 'b' and still at every step you are checking the condition -

```
if(a[i]>a[i+1])
```

Don't you think, 'b' has a role to play here?

Consider the above points and comment on this post if you still have issues.

Answer (score -1):

Not absolutely sure, but i think this should be the corrected implementation

```
static void bubbleSort() {
    int [] a = {1,3,4,2,5};
    for(int c = 0;c < a.length;c++){//now it does 
        for(int i = 0;i+1<a.length-c;i++){

            if(a[i]>a[i+1]){
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< a.length ; i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

You run over a again and again, but you changed b, which you didnt compare. So your first for loop was doing nothing. You dont need j, c works. Because if you made 1 cycle in the inner loop, the biggest number is at the end, so you dont have to check it again.
The c-loop should run till c

Comment: There's a `Homework` tag which means you shouldn't just give the corrected code plus the OP explicitly states (even in the original version of the question) that they do not want to be given code, they want to understand it. I'd suggest removing the code and fleshing out your explanation a bit.

Comment: i corrected his program and explained it afterwards. And he wanted his code to be modified, not a new implementation

Comment: You did, and I edited my comment accordingly. Either way, due to the tag and due to the OP explicit instructions I don't think you should include the code